# Git checkout commit hash in AOSP

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo

I never used [repo](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo) and I've just recently discovered that AOSP is composed of different git repositories.

My question is: how can I checkout between commits?

For example, let's consider [this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/+/ab39f6cb7afc48584da3c59d8e2a5e1ef121aafb)
which involves just one .java file (InstallStart.java)

I go to the folder that contains InstallStart.java, in my case:
`/mnt/aosp/Android/packages/apps/PackageInstaller/src/com/android/packageinstaller`

`git log` shows that I'm in git repository... but the checkout fails

```
git checkout 419c6b327562afc9af3bed5e92741e5bf190ec30
fatal: reference is not a tree: 419c6b327562afc9af3bed5e92741e5bf190ec30
```

Comment: Try `git fetch origin 419c6b327562afc9af3bed5e92741e5bf190ec30` first.

Comment: `fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

but I'm sure that `git log` shows the history

Comment: What's the output of `git remote -v` ?

Comment: If you want to merge 419c6 this commit, try `git merge FETCH_HEAD` after git fetch.

Comment: Using `git remote -v` I'am able to see the remote branches. Choosing one of them, I'm able to checkout a commit, thank you @KuanlinChen 

But after this operation I can't build the AOSP... do you know if there is a way of checkout to a Gerrit Change-Id?

Comment: Every changes on Gerrit have their corresponding commit-id.